# How edit in SQL Server from datagridview with LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I want to edit value of field in my database, from my datagridview.

When I execute my application, the row which has color red, I want to edit the 'bool_badge' value in my database.

For example: for id=3, 'bool_badge'=1 : when I click in button Check-Out , the 'bool_badge' should change to 0 in my database

[image]

I have in `dataGridView1_CellContentClick` condition for the button Check-Out

[image]

Code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                            "Message de confirmation",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

SO , here after this condition if ,I want to edit my database...

I tried:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
{
    int row = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                        "Message de confirmation",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {  
        using (checkinentrepriseEntities2 context = new checkinentrepriseEntities2())
        {
            badge badge = new badge();                     

            badge badverif = context.badge.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == row);

            if (badverif != null)
            {
                badverif.bool_badge = 0;
            }
```

But I know with this code, it doesn't work,

I have to find the exact ID for the ROW selected...and make relation with my database...but I don't know how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I think your example is wrong, _For example: for id=3, 'bool_badge'=1 : when I click in button Check-Out , the 'bool_badge' should change to 1 in my database_. Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: oh yes ! Sorry
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `RowIndex` was 2 and your `ID` was 3. You need to look at the cell value to get ID. It's not proper to get ID as `RowIndex`. What If IDs will be like 1,2,3,5,6,7 ? You should get `ID` like this and you should use `SaveChanges()` to update value

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                int row = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells["id"].Value; 
               // selected cells owning rows ID cell's value will give the ID
                if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                                  "Message de confirmation",
                                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    using (checkinentrepriseEntities2 context = new checkinentrepriseEntities2())
                    {
                        badge badg = new badge();

                        badge badverif = context.badge.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == row);

                        if (badverif != null)
                        {
                            badverif.bool_badge = 0;
                            context.SaveChanges(); // and savechanges after set update value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Thanks,

it has an Error!

'The column named id is not found'  !!! 

How doesn't it found the fiel 'id' ?

Comment: yes it is in the line :

  int row = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells["id"].Value;

Comment: Ok, make it `Cells[0]`.